# matplotlib.use('qt5agg') equivalent in cv2 - maOS

Tags: python, qt5, opencv

Hello I need to change to default `cv2` gui on macOS to use qt5 instead of `tkinter`.
I usually do it using `matplotlib` using `matplotlib.use('qt5agg')` which results in the window below. I need the same window layout for `cv2`

[image: example]

Comment: as I know `cv2` already use `PyQt` - at least on Linux. And probably on Windows too. See image in `cv` doc [Qt New Functions](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html). OR maybe it depens on what you have installed.

Comment: usingi Google `opencv GUI backend` I found on forum OpenCV: [Selecting GUI backends](https://answers.opencv.org/question/229647/selecting-gui-backends/). It seems it depend on how C/C++ code was compiled and you can't change it. Maybe build own window using PyQt.

Comment: i have only examples how to use `cv2.VideoCapture()` in own window in [wxPython](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/wxPython-CV-widget/main.py) or `tkinter`: [minimal version](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20minimal%20version/main.py) or [with buttons to start and stop](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20with%20buttons%20to%20start%20and%20stop/main.py)